# MomentJS - a cleaner way of getting an hourly price in the past 24 hours

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, momentjs

Thanks for all the help in advance.  I'll try to describe this as best as I can.

What I'm trying to do, is get a list of prices from an array that contains prices updated every minute.  Specifically, I would like a list of each price from every hour for the the past 24 hours. So 24 prices for one day in effect.  Each prices has a timestamp, so I'm using momentJS `isBefore` and `isAfter` to narrow down the search.

The code below shows how I am getting the data I need from the past two hours. This works fine.  But I don't feel right in replicating this 24 times. A loop should be able to give me what I need, however I'm not sure how to implement it.  Thanks so much for any help.  I'm sorry if I haven't described the issue well

```
const lastHourArray = [];
    const lastHourArray2 = [];
    lodash.forEach(tickerHistoryData, (data) => {
        const dateNow = moment();
        const prevHour = moment().subtract(1, 'hours');
        const prevTwoHours = moment().subtract(2, 'hours');
        const instanceDate = moment(data[0]);
        const isItAnHourAgo = instanceDate.isBefore(dateNow) && instanceDate.isAfter(prevHour);
        const isItTwoHoursAgo = instanceDate.isBefore(prevHour) && instanceDate.isAfter(prevTwoHours);

        if (isItAnHourAgo) {
            const hourObject = {
                hour: 1,
                price: data[4],
            };
            lastHourArray.push(hourObject);
        }
        if (isItTwoHoursAgo) {
            const hourObject2 = {
                hour: 2,
                price: data[4],
            };
            lastHourArray2.push(hourObject2);
        }
    });
    tickerInstruments[findInstrument.productSymbol].hourlyPrice.push(lastHourArray[lastHourArray.length - 1]);
    tickers[findInstrument.name].hourlyPrice.push(lastHourArray[lastHourArray.length - 1]);
    tickerInstruments[findInstrument.productSymbol].hourlyPrice.push(lastHourArray2[lastHourArray2.length - 1]);
    tickers[findInstrument.name].hourlyPrice.push(lastHourArray2[lastHourArray2.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
lodash.forEach(tickerHistoryData, (data) => {
  const dateNow = moment();
  const instanceDate = moment(data[0]);

  for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++) {
    const prevHour = moment().subtract(i, 'hours');
    const isItAnHourAgo = instanceDate.isBefore(dateNow) && instanceDate.isAfter(prevHour);

    if (isItAnHourAgo) {
      const hourObject = {
        hour: i,
        price: data[4],
      };
      lastHourArray.push(hourObject);
    }
  }
});
```

can you try will this work?
for every `data` in `tickerHistoryData` it will loop 24 times and check time.

if you need to check time from 0 to 23h, fix for loop like so `(let i = 0; i < 24; i++)`

Comment: thank you for the reply!  I think it's pretty close!  I think why it's going wrong for me is that there's a for loop inside a forEach.  I'm wondering if I just need to expand on the original forEach

Comment: well if you need to check for 24 hours for every instance of `data` then you'll need loop inside another loop, not sure how's your data structured.

if that's not the case, if every `data` represents every hour you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/bzcwxq08/

it just uses the index from the `forEach` loop

Comment: Thanks again!  I did make a little change, http://jsfiddle.net/wfnt7946/

As you can see, I set the dateNow to subtract i each time, as I'm looking for a specific value, not a range.  Currently, this works for me for two loops, but isItAnHourAgo is returning false on the third iteration.  I'm not sure why as the timestamps are correct

Comment: `const dateNow = moment().subtract(i - 1, 'hours');
const prevHour = moment().subtract(i, 'hours');`

maybe you need to switch these two, shouldn't `prevHour` be `i - 1`  and `dateNow` just `i`?

Comment: yep, you're right.  I have it working now the way I want it.  Thank so much for your help!